# How to make custom right click options?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm seeing some sites have custom right click options, instead of the usual ones if you click on a browser page: Back, forward, reload, etc.
How, without appending iv's or anything, to keep the right click graphics but set different options?

Comment: Check out this tutorial, looks like it will help:
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

Comment: @Practically - you should add this as an answer, the JavaScript contextmenu is one way of building custom right click options.